# how to make a loop for a play/pause button using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

so i have been trying to make a music player website and i`m stuck at trying to loop the play/pause script, i kept trying but i reached nothing
this is the javascript that i have been using, it does work for the first song but not the others

```
<pre>
var mySong = document.getElementById("mySong");
var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
icon.onclick = function () {
  if (mySong.paused) {
    mySong.play();
    icon.src = "/images/pause.png";
  } else {
    mySong.pause();
    icon.src = "/images/play.png";
  }
};
</pre>
```

and here is the html part that i`m trying to loop

```
<pre>
<div class="music-box">
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/a.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
              <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
              <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
              <audio id="mySong">
                <source src="/music/b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
              </audio>
              <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/play.png" id="icon" style="padding-right: 20px" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="music-play">
        <div class="play-image">
          <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="play-controls">
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="song-name">
              <h5>Dunkelheit</h5>
              <p>Burzum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="play-icon">
              <i class="fa fa-step-backward"> </i>
              <i class="fa fa-play"> </i>
              <i class="fa fa-step-forward"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="music-progress">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

this is my first time using stackoverflow so sorry for my poor documentation,hope you can provide me with solutions or tutorials as this is my first month of learning Front-end.
p.s:- sorry for my poor english as i`m not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, How do you want this code to work when you are using the same id for all audio songs :>, The id is only used once for an only element so to use it u should use class or data-[attribute] and select element, by the way, this is a link about the use of data-[] in short term [https://reactgo.com/select-element-data-attribute-js/#:~:text=To%20select%20the%20multiple%20elements,const%20elements%20%3D%20document](https://reactgo.com/select-element-data-attribute-js/#:%7E:text=To%20select%20the%20multiple%20elements,const%20elements%20%3D%20document).

```js
const songs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-songs]");
const icons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-icon]");

songs.forEach((song, index) => {

    icons[index].addEventListener('click', function () {
        songs.forEach(song => {
            song.pause();
        })
        //put code of icon here 
        if (song.paused) {
            song.play();
            // icon.src = "/images/pause.png";
        } else {
            song.pause();
            // icon.src = "/images/play.png";
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="music-box">
        <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
                <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
                <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
                <audio id="mySong" data-songs='1'>
                    <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
                </audio>
                <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/play1.png" id="icon" data-icon="1" style="padding-right: 20px;
            height:50px" />
        </div>
        <div class="music-info">
            <div class="music-img">
                <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="music-name">
                <h6>Single Song Title</h6>
                <audio id="mySong" data-songs='2'>
                    <source src="test2.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
                </audio>
                <p>Single name and music director</p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/play1.png" id="icon" data-icon="2" style="padding-right: 20px;
            height:50px" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="music-play">
        <div class="play-image">
            <img src="images/Filosofem.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="play-controls">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="song-name">
                    <h5>Dunkelheit</h5>
                    <p>Burzum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="play-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-step-backward"> </i>
                    <i class="fa fa-play"> </i>
                    <i class="fa fa-step-forward"> </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="music-progress">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: i tried your code and it worked well with a single song but when i try to run it with multiple songs using data-songs method nothing happens and i tried to console log it and it shows that all 12 songs got fired up at the same time when i click the first button however all the other 11 buttons wont do anything so it probably has to do with the #id

Comment: I Edited it because I forget to change the code of the icon so it know work fine try it

Comment: thanks man, i will never forget your help.

Comment: Happy to help my friend❤

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is that you created a EventHandler with jQuery and it looks for some element which have the id of "icon". But it is not how HTML works. You have more than one element having same id. It's incorrect.

The correct way of doing this is creating the EventHandler with **class** of "icon" **NOT** id of "icon". When the handler is triggered, you should change the "src" attribute of this element.

---

After I runned your HTML and JS I realized that you used Object.onclick attribute on your script to trig the function which changes the src attribute. You could not achieved what you wanted because you are trying to DOM your element with id's. Firstly, convert all id's to class. And then you should do something like below to set all of the image's onclick attributes to your function. You can not do it on collection of elements. You can do it one-by-one with for loop. (*You better use jQuery for this but since you are new to JS, try this usage and see what happens.*)

```
var mySong = document.getElementById("mySong");
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");

var clickFunction = function () {
  alert("kkk");
  if (mySong.paused) {
    mySong.play();
    icon.src = "/images/pause.png";
  } else {
    mySong.pause();
    icon.src = "/images/play.png";
  }
};


for (var i=0; i < icons.length; i++) {
    icons[i].onclick = clickFunction;
};
```

Comment: i tried this
`<pre>
var mySong = document.getElementsByClassName("mySong");
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
  icon.onclick = function () {
    if (mySong.paused) {
      mySong.play();
      icon.src = "/images/pause.png";
    } else {
      mySong.pause();
      icon.src = "/images/play.png";
    }
  };
}
</pre> `
yet nothing happened

Comment: It was also the first thing I did, but since document.getElementsByClassName returning a collection of elements you are supposed to create a for loop to set every element's onclick attribute to your function as I did.

Comment: first i want to say thank you for you help now i all buttons are playing a song
second the only problem left is that they are all playing the same song , so like if i press the button that plays the first song now all buttons will continue to play the same song but when i refresh and press another button a different song becomes the song that is getting repeated on all buttons and so on, which probably has to do with the fact that "mySong" is an ID and class, any idea on how to change that? so that each button plays a different song

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked! Since it's another problem please close this question by approving my answer then create another one with updated version of your code and question. It's better to keep StackOverflow clean and understandable from the sight of someone else just Googling around and seeing your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "looping the audio", but part of the problem may be that you do not have independent id values for your audio elements in your HTML. the "id" attribute should give each audio element a unique identifier, but you have given the id of "mySong" to **each** audio element in your file.

If you want them to sequentially move from one audio clip to another, you could consider concatenating the audio outside of the browser and then uploading a single audio element. Without more information regarding what specifically you're looking for, it will be difficult to address.